# Choropleth in R: custom breaks and plotting

Tags: r, choropleth

I have a question with regard to plotting a choropleth map. 
What is recommended with regard to plotting a map with custom breaks? And make it look a bit attractive.

In my [script](http://pastebin.com/MXFXy4tV) I have used the plot and spplot command to visualize some data but I am not entirely happy with the result.
It is easy to see why. Using [spplot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AMsya.jpg) I get a colour ramp that repeats colours for different values which is a bit weird.
Using [plot with the custom breaks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K2FCt.jpg) I have not been able to make better intervals for the values, such that for instance zero-values are white on the map. The skewed proportions between legend and map are I think probably the result of Rstudio.

So I wondered whether someone has better suggestions for plotting choropleth maps in R using custom breaks?

**EDIT 20-02-2013**

As suggested I have used ggplot2 for creating a choropleth map. I've used the code below. I encountered two problems. One is that after fortifying the data not all data from the shapefile is transferred to the data frame. So I have to rename the "id" variable such that I can merge the data. Minor issue.

A bigger issue is that despite the fact that the data in the dataframe is correct, the ggplot shows a map where the data is incorrect. The colour value according to the legend does not correspond with the value of the variable in the data. Am I overlooking something here?

```
# Plotting polygon shapefiles (try-out)
# Load the packages
require(rgdal)
require(maptools)
require(ggplot2)
gpclibPermit() # required for the fortify method
# Load the shapefile
africa=readOGR("/home/GIS",layer="africaII")
names(africa) 
# Load the data on conflict
conflict<-read.csv("africa_conflict.csv", header=TRUE)
names(conflict)
# Merge the data together
africadat<-merge(africa, conflict, by="ISO3")
# Changing the data in the shapefile
africa@data <- africadat
# Fortify so that ggplot can plot
africa.points = fortify(africa,region="ISO3")
# Change "id" to "ISO3"such that the datasets can be merged again
names(africa.points)[names(africa.points)=="id"]<-"ISO3"
africa.df=merge(africa.points,africadat,by="ISO3")
# Plot the data
ggplot(africa.df) + 
aes(long,lat,group=group) + 
geom_polygon(aes(fill =onset))+
geom_path(color="white") +
coord_equal()
```

[Link to replication data](https://www.dropbox.com/s/7huevituqc4pq7j/ggplot%20bottleneck.zip)

**Update 13-11-2015:** 
Fixed link to [shape file](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/wxcbb4vr894s9gj/AAALneotvdQtzsXEFm4Q64H2a?dl=0).
See answer below for solution on how to plot the choropleth.

Comment: I would also look at using `ggplot2` for choropleth maps, which I think turns out better looking output by default.

Comment: Yeah I wasn't sure about using ggplot2 since the long/lat data in my shapefile only specifies a point and not the outline of the national borders. So therefore I used these plots in order to create a choropleth map. I'm not very familiar with handling GIS data in R so not sure if I'm overlooking some really straightforward solution for that.

Comment: Please fix the link to the shapefile.

Comment: Sure, no problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the archives, the solution I used:

```
#### Choropleth in R example ####

## Libraries
library(classInt)    
library(lattice)
library(RColorBrewer)    
library(sp)

## Shapefile for Sub-Sahara Africa (see link in Q)
africa<-readShapeSpatial("shp/africa.shp") 

## Add data to shapefile
# In this case the number of conflict onsets between 1981-2010
africa$onset<-c(3,0,3,1,3,1,4,2,3,0,
                2,0,3,1,1,0,2,1,1,1,
                2,0,3,0,1,0,0,4,2,1,
                3,0,1,0,6,1,3,1,1,0,
                0,1,1,0,0,0,0)

## Plot 
par(mar=c(1,4,1,1),family="serif")
trellis.par.set(axis.line=list(col=NA)) # Remove borders
spplot(africa,zcol="onset",col.regions=colorRampPalette(c("white","grey10"))(20),
main=list(label="Number of civil conflict onsets 1981-2010",cex=3),
pretty=T,par.settings=list(axis.text=list(cex=3)))
```

[image]

Comment: There is a package for R which offers useful mapping functionality. It is called **[cartography](https://github.com/Groupe-ElementR/cartography)** (and notably allows to [choropleth maps](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/cartography/vignettes/cartography.html#choropleth-map) according to the documentation). Sorry if it's off topic (as you already found your answer) but let's say it's for future reference..!

Comment: That looks pretty nice. I'll certainly give it a try for other work, so thanks for the reference.

Answer (score 6):

I don't see a problem with the above code except that you have 6 clear levels in `onset`, so I would treat them as factors rather than as a continuous variable. Note the `factor` call in the code below.

```
ggplot(africa.df) +
  aes(long,lat,group=group) +
  geom_polygon(aes(fill = factor(onset)))+
  geom_path(color="white") +
  coord_equal()
```

That code gives the following result:

[image: original]

If you want custom colours you could try this:

```
library(RColorBrewer)
my.cols <- brewer.pal(6, "Blues")

ggplot(africa.df) +
  aes(long,lat,group=group) +
  geom_polygon(aes(fill = factor(onset)))+
  scale_fill_manual("Onset\n", values = my.cols, guide = "legend") +
  geom_path(color="white") +
  coord_equal()
```

Which produces this:

[image: custom colours]

Comment: It still plots the wrong values though. Very peculiar.

Comment: OK, can you specify exactly what the issue is, with examples? Angola is assigned a `3` for the `onset` column and plots a `3` in the chart. That seems to work. Presumably I'm missing something?

Comment: Ow yes sorry. Angola is one of the few that is correct. If you look at South Africa, Namibia, or Senegal for instance you'll see that the value as indicated by the colour does not correspond with the value in the data. So Senegal should be a 6(now a 2), South Africa 0 (4) and Namibia also 0 (1). Burundi and Rwanda are also off to name a few other. In the [link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/5x5gyvicbuuqgv7/Rplot01.png) a plot I made with spplot which shows a map with the correct values. This plot is done directly from the shapefile. So I guess something goes wrong with creating the dataframe.

Answer (score 5):

The classInt package has a number of functions for computing intervals for numeric data - install it and read the docs.

Comment: Yes, I used the classInt package with fixed breaks (not shown in the script) but the issue with that is that it computes intervals for continuous numerical data. Whereas my intervals are discrete, they represent a frequency of events. Haven't found out yet how to improve upon that.